# TimePickerFragment two buttons

Tags: android, android-timepicker

I have a TimePickerFragment and a onTimeSet to do an action after select the time. The problem is, I have two buttons to select time and I don't know how to know which one user used. I tried a switch but it `cannot resolve symbol`.

any ideas how to know which button user select?

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

...

public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

        switch(view) {
            case R.id.bstart: //cannot resolve symbol
                Toast.makeText(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getApplicationContext(), "button 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.bend:
                Toast.makeText(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getApplicationContext(), "button 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }


    }
```

### if needed:

my buttons:

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
...
/>

 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
...
/>
```

mainActivity (sum up)

```
public Button bstart;
public Button bend;

bstart = findViewById(R.id.button);
bend = findViewById(R.id.button2);

bstart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                showTimePickerDialog(v);
            }
        });

bend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                showTimePickerDialog(v);
            }
        });



public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the constructor for your TimePickerFragment take the view id.
In your main activity:

```
DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment(v.getId());
```

In your TimePickerFragment:

```
private String viewId;

public TimePickerFragment(String viewId) {
    super();
    this.viewId = viewId;
}
```

Comment: the `v.getId()` show me this: `TimePickerFragment() in TimePickerFragment cannot be applied to (int)`

Comment: @RickJoe You added the constructor that I show in my answer to your TimePickerFragment class?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a bundle to your fragment.

```
public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("","");
    newFragment.setArguments(args);
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
}
```

Then in your fragment class you can get the arguments with

```
Bundle args = getArguments();
args.getString("","");
```

You will need to make changes appropriately as I could not test the syntax at this time. But that is the general idea of how you can get parameters into a fragment.